# dijit widgets inside a custom widget -- handling their events

Tags: dojo

JS:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dojo/dom",
    "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/MainViewWidget.html",
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"],
    function(declare, dom, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, template){
        return declare("package.MainViewWidget", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin], {
            widgetsInTemplate: true,
            templateString: template,
            constructor: function(){

            },
            startup: function(){

            },
            search: function(evt){
                alert('hi');
                alert(evt);
            }
        });
    });
```

templates/MainViewWidget.html:

```
<div class="mainContainer">


<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left', splitter:true"> 
        <h2>List of trips</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange:'search'"/>
        <br />

    </div>


    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="tabContainerDiv" data-dojo-props="region: 'center', tabPosition: 'top', tabStrip:'true', style:'width:80%;height:100%'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Summary" data-dojo-props="selected:'true', title:'About'">Welcome. Navigate through the Left pane.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The thing is, I want to capture events on the `TextBox`. I was looking to do this with just markup as you can see from `data-dojo-attach-event="onchange:'search'"`. I have tried many variations of this and I can't get it to work. Basically what I want is to define a function in JS and attach it as handler in the markup. Please help.

Comment: Did you try it in dojo 1.10? It's working in my widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported, sadly. I just spent about two hours discovering this. Any node in your template with a `data-dojo-type` attribute is ignored by `_TemplatedMixin._attachTemplateNodes` (see [line 177](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.8/_TemplatedMixin.js#L177)). In other words, `data-dojo-attach-event` will only bind to plain DOM nodes (not Dijits).

This at least applies to v1.8. The attach processing is different in v1.9 (there's an [`_AttachMixin`](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_AttachMixin.js)), so it might work there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:search"
```

Camelcase onChange, and no quotes around search.